# How do I pause autoscrolling of an Android application?

Tags: java, android

I have created this Android layout:

[image: Custom Android Layout]

This has a custom title bar and a TextView containing some sample text. The TextView is inside a ScrollView.

The 'start/stop' button is supposed to start and stop the text automatically scrolling.

I am using a Scroller object but I can't find a method to pause the scrolling. Does such a method exist or should I be using an alternative approach (and if so, what)?

Answer (score -1):

Put speed = 0